# How to handle time zone for stores located in diff time zone

Tags: datetime, timezone

I have web application which controls the stores locate din different time zones.
In this web application user will set rules that, any particular product is in discount for any given period of time i.e. 1-Aug 2014 to 5-Aug-2014. so how can this rule be executed in web application. this info can be inserted from anytime zone. but store in Europe and Store in US should have to make this product available from exact 1-Aug-2014, Europe will be early compare to US.
SO how we can handle this kind of scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

In general:

- Store the time zone for each store, such as `America/Los_Angeles` or `Europe/London`.
- When checking for discounts, get the current UTC time and use the store's time zone to determine the appropriate local time.
- Compare that local time against the expiration date for the discount.

This assumes that the business rule is to rely upon the store location's time zone.  This might not necessarily be the case - as many online stores serve customers worldwide without regard to where the physical store or product is located.  In that case, you need to determine who's time zone is applicable.  Is it a single fixed time zone for the whole company?  Or perhaps it's aligned the end-user's time zone, such that those in different time zones would have the offer expire at different times.  You'll need to decide what is appropriate for your particular business.

Sorry I can't be more specific, but you didn't provide many details to go on.  If you need further assistance, please consider editing your question to include details such as what language and platform you're using, what code you have tried, and what the specific business rules are.